# Android coming from camera loses fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, fragmenttransaction

I have implemented a formular which has some steps. Every step is in a new `Fragment` using a `FrameLayout`.

In the last step (`FRAGMENT A`) there is a `Button`. When this `Button` is clicked a new `Fragment` (`FRAGMENT B`) and the Camera `Intent` are launched.

**Sometimes** after the photo is taken and the Camera is dismissed, the `FRAGMENT A` is shown instead of the `FRAGMENT B`. When this happens, the `UI` elements are frozen, any field is clikable and the only way to continue using the app is closing the `Form` and start the process again.

I thought it was a `OOM` error so the `Activity` gets killed / restored and the last state wasn´t correctly stored.

I've tried to check that but the method `onRestoreInstanceState()` is not called. Also methods from the `FRAGMENT B` are called after the camera is closed whether it is shown or not. This is the code I called to open the `FRAGMENT B` and the camera:

**BASE FRAGMENT**

```
private void setCurrentFragment(int pos, boolean animate) {
   showFragment(buildFragment(mCurrentPage), animate, animationFromRight);
   ....
}

private Fragment buildFragment(int pos) {
    switch (mHasFamilyManager ? pos : pos + 1) {
        ............
        case 3:
            mCurrentFragment = PhotoVerificationFragment.newInstance();
            if (mState.getAttachments().isEmpty()) {
                switch (mState.getPictureSelector()) {
                    .....
                    case CAMERA:
                        onAddCameraPictureClicked();
                        break;
                }
             .....

    return mCurrentFragment;
}

private void showFragment(final Fragment fragment, boolean animate,
        final boolean animationFromRight) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (animate) {
            if (animationFromRight) {
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.activity_slide_in_right,
                        R.anim.activity_slide_out_left);
            } else {
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.activity_slide_in_left,
                        R.anim.activity_slide_out_right);
            }
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public void onAddCameraPictureClicked() {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
    .....
}
```

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
transaction.commit();
```

By using `replace` you are replacing fragments on top of each other, so it does not remove the previous fragment or it is adding the new fragment below the current one.

Using `add` you make sure that it will be always on top.

`disallowAddToBackStack` will make sure that you are not holding anything in the stack.